# How to remove percentage and resource column from tooltip on VUE Google Chart Gantt

Tags: vue.js, charts, gantt-chart

I'm working on my VUE project which uses vue google chart gantt to display task management, and I encountered with tooltip, which has information such as name of project, deadlines, percentage, and resourcen. But I wanna remove **percentage** and **resources** from tooltip by deleting column on **chartData** array, but it doesn't work, and in the documentation [Google Chart Gantt](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/ganttchart) I didn't find any related tooltip config,

[image]

```
<template>
  <div>
    <GChart
      :settings="{ packages: ['gantt'] }"
      type="Gantt"
      :data="chartData"
      :options="chartOptions"
    />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { GChart } from "vue-google-charts/legacy";
export default {
  components: { GChart },
  data() {
    return {
      chartData: [
        [
          { type: "string", label: "Task ID" },
          { type: "string", label: "Task Name" },

          <!-- try to delete this two column -->
          { type: "string", label: "Resource" },
          <!-- try to delete this two column -->

          { type: "date", label: "Start Date" },
          { type: "date", label: "End Date" },
          { type: "number", label: "Duration" },

         <!-- try to delete this two column -->
          { type: "number", label: "Percent Complete" },
          { type: "string", label: "Dependencies" },
         <!-- try to delete this two column -->

        ],
        [
          "2022Spring",
          "Spring 2022",
          <!-- try to delete this two column -->
          "spring",
          <!-- try to delete this two column -->
          new Date(2022, 5, 22),
          new Date(2022, 6, 20),
          null,
          <!-- try to delete this two column -->
          null,
          null,
          <!-- try to delete this two column -->
        ],
        [
          "2014Summer",
          "Summer 2014",
          <!-- try to delete this two column -->
          "summer",
          <!-- try to delete this two column -->
          new Date(2022, 5, 3),
          new Date(2022, 5, 28),
          null,
          <!-- try to delete this two column -->
          100,
          null,
          <!-- try to delete this two column -->
        ]
      ],
      chartOptions: {
        height: 600,
        chart: {
          title: "Gantt",
        },
        gantt: {
          trackHeight: 50,
          labelStyle: {
            fontSize: 16,
            color: "#757575",
          },
          percentEnabled: false,
        },
        tooltip: {
          text: "value",
        },
      },
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

when I try to delete those two, I got error, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[The 'Resource' you can omit by omitting the column and it's data](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-worker-qsw7yu?file=/src/components/google-chart/GoogleChartData.js).

The percentage you can't omit.

[Customising the tooltip](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content#supported-charts) within a Gantt Chart is also not an option as this isn't supported for Gantt Charts.